# How to Create Opportunity Line Items in Test Classes

Tags: apex, unit-test, change-set

All the test classes are on opportunitylineitem.  I tried testing each test classes all are running with code coverage more than 75% in sandbox as well as production.  When I try to migrate the newly written trigger its throwing Error .  When I checked the test classes, I could see the lines are opportunitylineitem.

At AccOppsegmentTestClass :The Error line is insert olii and in the test class it is declared as

```
OpportunityLineItem olii = new OpportunityLineItem (Quantity=2, OpportunityId=opp.Id, TotalPrice=10, PriceBookEntryId='01ud0000004YWFqAAO'); 
insert olii;
```

At BlxOppclonecontrollerTestClass :The Error line is insert olli and in the test class it is declared as

```
OpportunityLineItem olli = new OpportunityLineItem (Quantity=2, OpportunityId=opp1.Id, TotalPrice=10, PriceBookEntryId='01ud0000004YWFqAAO'); 
insert olli;
```

At Oli_multiple_Products_TestClass :The Error line is insert ooli and in the test class it is declared as

```
OpportunityLineItem ooli = new OpportunityLineItem (Quantity=2, OpportunityId=opp.Id, TotalPrice=10, PriceBookEntryId='01ud0000004YWFqAAO'); 
insert ooli;
```

Error as :

```
AccOppsegmentTestClass  validateAccOppsegment   System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, Populate_Extension: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Trigger.Populate_Extension: line 15, column 1: []
    Stack Trace: Class.AccOppsegmentTestClass.validateAccOppsegment: line 19, column 1
```

Similarly for other test class i do get the same error.Any help very much appreciated

Trigger :

```
trigger Populate_Extension on OpportunityLineItem (Before Insert) {

 //List<OpportunityLineItem> oli= new List<OpportunityLineItem>();

  Set<Id> pbeIds = new Set<Id>();

 for (OpportunityLineItem opli : Trigger.new) {
    pbeIds.add(opli.PricebookEntryId);
 }

Map<Id, PricebookEntry> pbeMap = new Map<Id, PricebookEntry>([select Id, Product2.Product_Line__c from PricebookEntry where Id in :pbeIds]);

 for(OpportunityLineItem opli:Trigger.new){

          if(pbeMap.get(opli.PricebookEntryId).Product2.Product_Line__c == 'DIE'){
          system.debug('PricebookEntry.Product2.ProductLine!!!!!!!!!'+opli.PricebookEntry.Product2.Product_Line__c);

            opli.UnitPrice=0.01;
            system.debug('Unitprice%%%%%%%%%%%%'+opli.UnitPrice);

           opli.Newextension__c=opli.Quantity*0.01;
           system.debug('Newextension@@@@@@@@@@@'+opli.Newextension__c);


        }

        else {


            opli.UnitPrice=1;
            system.debug('Unitprice^^^^^^^^^^^^^^'+opli.UnitPrice);

            opli.Newextension__c=opli.Quantity*1;
            system.debug('Newextension$$$$$$$$$$$'+opli.Newextension__c);


      }

    }

}
```

Test class :

```
@istest
public class Populate_ExtensionTestclass{

static testmethod void  PopulateExtensiontest(){

Date closeDt = Date.Today();

 date myDate = date.today();

Account a2 = new Account(Name ='icrm testing acc');
insert a2;

opportunity oppr = new opportunity(Name='testing DIE 4/6/2015' ,  AccountId= a2.Id,StageName = 'Prospecting', 
                                   CloseDate = closeDt);
insert oppr;

 Pricebook2 pb22 = new Pricebook2(Name='testDIE');
 insert pb22;

Product2 pro2 = new Product2(Product_Line__c='DIE',Name='BXCD',Product_Code_Item_Number__c='BXCD24', isActive=true);
insert pro2;

PricebookEntry pbe2 =new PricebookEntry(unitprice=0.01,Product2Id=pro2.Id,Pricebook2Id=Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
                                         isActive=true,UseStandardPrice = false);
 insert pbe2;

 OpportunityLineItem OPplineitem2 = new OpportunityLineItem (Quantity=2, OpportunityId=oppr.Id,UnitPrice=0.01,PriceBookEntryId=pbe2.Id,
                                     Newextension__c=0.02,Bin_Item_Code__c='BXCD2424');
 insert OPplineitem2;
 }
 static testmethod void  PopulateExtensiontest1(){

Date closeDt = Date.Today();

 date myDate = date.today();

Account a2 = new Account(Name ='Non icrm testing acc');
insert a2;

opportunity oppr = new opportunity(Name='testing NONDIE 4/6/2015' ,  AccountId= a2.Id,StageName = 'Prospecting', 
                                   CloseDate = closeDt);
insert oppr;

 Pricebook2 pb22 = new Pricebook2(Name='testNonDIE');
 insert pb22;

Product2 pro2 = new Product2(Product_Line__c='NONDIE',Name='BXCDXXX',Product_Code_Item_Number__c='BXCD2424', isActive=true);
insert pro2;

PricebookEntry pbe2 =new PricebookEntry(unitprice=1,Product2Id=pro2.Id,Pricebook2Id=Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
                                         isActive=true,UseStandardPrice = false);
 insert pbe2;

 OpportunityLineItem OPplineitem2 = new OpportunityLineItem (Quantity=25, OpportunityId=oppr.Id,UnitPrice=1,PriceBookEntryId=pbe2.Id,
                                     Newextension__c=25);
 insert OPplineitem2;
 }
 }
```

Comment: can you share your Populate_Extension trigger code as well

Comment: @ Vamsi Krishna:I have updates the trigger and test class.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: If Chris' answer has solved your question, please make sure to mark his answer as accepted. It is a good practice to encourage users to answer, verify to visitors of your question that it's valid, and a kind way to tell the person who took the time to answer your question, "Thanks".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When working with Opportunity Line Items in Test Classes, you need to first make sure you have a pricebook, then you need to create a product, then you need to create a pricebook entry and then you can create an Opportunity Line Item.

See the code snippets below on how to create a Opporunity Line Item in a test class.

```
// This is how we get the Standard PriceBook Id.  Prior to Summer '14, we needed
// to use SeeAllData=true, so this is a big improvement
Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

//Create your product
Product2 prod = new Product2(
     Name = 'Product X',
     ProductCode = 'Pro-X',
     isActive = true
);
insert prod;

//Create your pricebook entry
PricebookEntry pbEntry = new PricebookEntry(
     Pricebook2Id = pricebookId,
     Product2Id = prod.Id,
     UnitPrice = 100.00,
     IsActive = true
);
insert pbEntry;

//create your opportunity line item.  This assumes you already have an opportunity created, called opp
OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem(
     OpportunityId = opp.Id,
     Quantity = 5,
     PricebookEntryId = pbEntry.Id,
     TotalPrice = quantity * pbEntry.UnitPrice
);
insert oli;
```

Comment: :Thanks for your reply.So we need to add seealldata=true for the test classes ,while using Test.getStandardPricebookId.In my test classes RecordTypeid is also hardcoded so I need to replace them also.

Comment: @nikkey It's best practice to create test data in your test class, instead of setting seealldata to true. See https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_testsetup_using.htm

What Chris is saying that you don't need to use seealldata anymore, because Test.getStandardPricebookId()

Comment: Exactly, thank you @Folkert.  Now that `Test.getStandardPricebookId()` exists, we **don't** need to use `SeeAllData=true`, which is a great improvement.

Comment: if using custom pricebooks, you'll need to insert a PBE for the standard pricebook first and then insert the PBE for the custom pricebook

Comment: @ crop1645:In my test classes RecordTypeid is also hardcoded so I need to replace with value or RecordTypename